# auto generated key in Riak via Java client

Tags: auto-generate, riak, java-client

Riak supports auto generated keys when storing an object:

http://wiki.basho.com/Basic-Riak-API-Operations.html:

> **Store a new object and assign random key #**
>
> If your application would rather leave key-generation up to Riak, issue a POST request to
> the bucket URL instead of a PUT to a bucket/key pair: POST
> /riak/bucket If you don’t pass Riak a “key” name after the bucket, it
> will know to create one for you.

is it possible to do the same when using the java client?
it seems that key must be provided when storing an object.

Comment: I've updated the answer below. This is now supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited to update:** This is now available in  the Java client. It was added in the 1.0.7 client release. See: https://github.com/basho/riak-java-client/pull/168

---

Unfortunately ... right now the Java client doesn't support this.

Someone has opened an issue for this: https://github.com/basho/riak-java-client/issues/141

I agree that it needs to be added. We've got a number of things we're working on at the moment for the Riak 1.2 release that are slightly higher priority, but I hope to work on this and get it added in the near future.

Comment: Hey @Brian I see that you made this update but I'm still having issues getting this to work. Bucket bucket = this.myClient.fetchBucket(bucketName).execute();
    bucket.store(POJO).withoutFetch().execute(); is throwing riak.client.convert.NoKeySpecifedException: null

Comment: Just a note, the above example is using the PB Client.

Comment: @KRB - I'm guessing I missed that in the JSON converter. I'll open an issue on it and fix it; sorry about that.

Comment: See: https://github.com/basho/riak-java-client/issues/245 - I'll try to get to it in the next couple days.